# A method out of render method, inside the App class in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, methods

So, hello everybody, I think this is a quick and simple question. Okay, I am trying to learn ReactJS and this is the one of the examples, this was once called a 'method' by my instructor:

```
videoSearch(term){
        YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: term}, (videos) => {
            this.setState({ 
                videos: videos,
                selectedVideo: videos[0] 
            });         
        });
    }
```

So this is basically a function, right? But when I try to call it like this:

```
const videoSearch = (term) => { blablabla }
```

... it doesn't work the same way, I don't get it why?

Comment: please add more info to your question, or better host your demo code somewhere like react-sandbox so. In the current form this does not seems to convey anything

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work in the same way?

Comment: Can someone help me on this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `const` when you are defining your arrow functions in your class. Just skip the `const` part.

```
videoSearch = (term) => { blablabla };
```

This is by definition:
[proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)

When we use regular functions in our class we skip the `function` part. Similarly we skip `const` part in our arrow function.

Comment: I got it mate but I don't understand why I'm not allowed to put a const there or even function videoSearch(term)....?

Comment: It's by definition. When you use regular function in your class you skip the `function` part already. Similarly you skip `const` part in your arrow function. I will edit my answer and expand it. Please consider answering it.